# Some not freed data in code

Tags: c, heap-memory

please try to help me, I'm stuck with this code for a long time and I need some help with it. So this code need to ask the user how much friend's he have and open a array of names by the size. Than there options to change one of the names and to change all the array by another friends. It's all work well but the heap memory didn't get freed.. I'd check with DR. Memory; 
please help me! :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LENGTH 20

void printsFriends(int friends, char** friendBook);
void changeFriends(int friends, char** friendsBook);
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0, num = 0,friends=0;
    char str[LENGTH];
    int flag = 0;
    int changeTo = 0;
    printf("Hello friend,how U doin'?\nTell me how many friends do you have?\n");
    scanf("%d", &friends);
    getchar();
    char** friendBook = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*friends);
    changeTo = friends;
    if (friendBook)
    {

        for (i = 0; i < changeTo; i++)
        {
            friendBook[i] = malloc(LENGTH*sizeof(char));
        }
        changeFriends(changeTo, friendBook);
        printsFriends(changeTo, friendBook);
        while (!flag)
        {
            printf("\n\nPlease enter one of options:\n1.Change name of friend\n2.Change number of friends\n3.Exit and free the memory\n");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            getchar();
            switch (num)
            {
                case 1:
                    printf("What number of friend do you want to change?\n");
                    scanf("%d", &num);
                    getchar();
                    printf("Enter name to change for\n");
                    fgets(str, LENGTH, stdin);
                    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;
                    friendBook[num - 1] =realloc(friendBook[num-1], (sizeof(char)*(strlen(str) + 1)));
                    if (*(friendBook + num - 1))
                    {
                        strcpy(*(friendBook + num - 1), str);
                    }
                    printsFriends(changeTo, friendBook);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("Enter number of friends you want:\n");
                    scanf("%d", &changeTo);
                    getchar();
                    friendBook = (char**)realloc(friendBook,sizeof(char*)*changeTo);
                    for (i = 0; i < changeTo; i++)
                    {
                        friendBook[i] = malloc(LENGTH*sizeof(char));
                    }
                    changeFriends(changeTo,friendBook );
                    printsFriends(changeTo, friendBook);                    
                    break;
                case 3:
                    flag = 1;
                    printf("BYE BYE!\n");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("not good choice, enter again\n");
                    break;

            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < changeTo; i++)
    {
        free(friendBook[i]);
    }
    free(friendBook);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

/*
This function get number of friends and friends book pointer to pointer and prints all the names.
input: number of friends and pointer to pointer of char's(array of strings)
output: none
*/
void printsFriends(int friends, char** friendBook)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < friends; i++)
    {
        printf("Friend: %s\tLength of friend name %d\n", friendBook[i], strlen(friendBook[i]));
    }
}
/*
this function gets number of friends and friends book and save to the array of strings names from stdin by the length of every string.
input: friends number and array of strings
output: none
*/
void changeFriends(int friends, char** friendBook)
{
    int i = 0;
    char str[LENGTH];
    for (i = 0; i < friends; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter friend number %d: \n", i + 1);
        fgets(str, LENGTH, stdin);
        str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;
        friendBook[i] = realloc(friendBook[i], (sizeof(char)*(strlen(str) + 1)));        // dynamic memory for every string(name)
        if (friendBook[i])
        {
            strcpy(friendBook[i], str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what DR is, but if you use linux and `valgrind`, then run it with `--track-origins=yes`.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever calling option 2, the old `friendBook[i]` pointers (for each `i`) are not freed.